# Two skeleton of one category are isomorphic

Tags: category-theory

I have the next doubt about this problem:

If $K_{1}$ and $K_{2}$ are two skeleton of the category $A$ i have to show that these two skeleton are isomorphic.

Because $K_{i}$ is  a skeleton  we have that the inclusion functor $I_{i}:K_{i}\rightarrow A$ is an equivalence of categories. I mean there is a functor $F_{i}:A\rightarrow K_{i}$  such that:

$\eta_{a}:a\rightarrow I_{1}F_{1}(a)$   $\;\;\;$  $\;\;\;$  $\varepsilon_{k_{1}}:F_{1}I_{1}(k_{1})\rightarrow k_{1}$

and

$\alpha_{a}:a\rightarrow I_{2}F_{2}(a)$ $\;\;\;$  $\;\;\;$  $\phi_{k_{2}}:F_{2}I_{2}(k_{2})\rightarrow k_{2}$

are natural isomorphisms with $a\in Obj(A)$,$\;\;$ $k_{1}\in Obj(K_{1})$ $\; $ and $k_{2}\in Obj(K_{2})$; $\;$ then I consider the next functor:

$F_{i}I_{j}:K_{j}\rightarrow K_{i}$ with $i,j\in \{1,2\}$ and $i\not=j$ I have trouble when I have show that:

$F_{1}I_{2}F_{2}I_{1}=1_{K_{1}}$  and $\;$ $F_{2}I_{1}F_{1}I_{2}=1_{K_{2}}$ in objects and morphisms because I have only isomorphisms in objects and morphisms I don't know what to do.

Thank you for your time!!!

--------------Edit---------------

We have:

$\begin{eqnarray}
F_{1}I_{2}F_{2}I_{1}(k_{1})&\cong& F_{1}I_{1}(k_{1})\\
&\cong&k_{1}
\end{eqnarray}$

The first line is because $\alpha_{I_{1}(k_{1})}:I_{1}(k_{1})\rightarrow I_{2}F_{2}(I_{1}(k_{1}))$ is an isomorphism and the second line is $\varepsilon_{k_{1}}$ is an isomorphism. By definition of $K_{1}$ being a skeleton (there is not exist an isomorphism between distinct objects in $K_{1}$), it follows that: $F_{1}I_{2}F_{2}I_{1}(k_{1})=k_{1}$

--------------Edit 2---------------

The idea is for $a\in Obj(K_{1})$ i have that $\varphi_{a}:a\rightarrow F_{2}(a)$ is an isomorphism so i define

$F:K_{1}\rightarrow K_{2}$ in objects $F(a)=F_{2}(a)$  and for $\gamma:a\rightarrow b$ $F(\gamma)=\varphi_{b}\circ \gamma\circ \varphi_{a}^{-1}$ (is there any difeference if i choose another isomorphism between $a$ and $F_{2}(a)$?)

It is a functor for $f:a\rightarrow b$ and $h:b\rightarrow c$

$\begin{eqnarray}
F(h\circ f)&=&\varphi_{c}\circ h\circ f \circ \varphi_{a}^{-1}\\
&=&\varphi_{c}\circ h\circ\varphi_{b}^{-1}\circ \varphi_{b} \circ f \circ \varphi_{a}^{-1}\\
&=&F(h)\circ F(f)
\end{eqnarray}$

and $F(1_{a})=1_{F_{2}(a)}$

And I define $G:K_{2}\rightarrow K_{1}$  in objects $G(F_{2}(a))=a$  and for $\tau:F_{2}(a)\rightarrow F_{2}(b)$ $G(\tau)=\varphi_{b}^{-1}\circ \tau\circ \varphi_{a}$

It is clear that $GF(a)=a$ and $FG(F_{2}(a))=F_{2}(a)$ and

$
\begin{eqnarray}
GF(\gamma)&=&G(\varphi_{b}\circ \gamma\circ \varphi_{a}^{-1})\\
&=& \varphi_{b}^{-1}\circ\varphi_{b}\circ \gamma\circ \varphi_{a}^{-1}\circ\varphi_{a}\\
&=&\gamma
\end{eqnarray}
$

and it is  analogous $FG(\tau)=\tau$

Comment: How do i use that for morphism?

Comment: Just use naturality.

Comment: is it because $\varepsilon_{a}\circ(F_{1}\alpha_{I_{1}(a)})^{-1} =1_{a}$ for $a\in Obj(K_{1})$?  which is because $K_{1}$ is a skeleton

Comment: Yes, and also that is is a natural transformation.

Comment: Thank you!!! that was tricky because today i just learn the definition of a Skeleton and i do not have enough experience with that definition.

Comment: @Nex False, skeletons can have non-identity isomorphisms.

Comment: I know it can be an isomorphism in the skeleton, however if that happen the domain and the codomain of the isomorphism must be equal. How do i prove for morphisms?

Comment: I was talking nonsense sorry.

Answer (score 2):

So, $K_1$ and $K_2$ are skeletons of category $A$, i.e. full subcategories having exactly one object from each isomorphism class.

For each $a\in Ob K_1$, let $F_2(a)$ be its isomorphic correspondent in $K_2$, and fix an isomorphism $\varphi_a:a\to F_2(a)$ within category $A$.

This $F_2$ is invertible, and gives the correspondence between the objects of $K_1$ and $K_2$, as both are skeletons of $A$.

Now for morphisms, map an arrow $\gamma:a\to b$ in $K_1$ to $\varphi_b\circ\gamma\circ\varphi_a^{-1}:F_2(a)\to F_2(b)$.

Comment: Do you mean i  use the  unit $\phi_{a}:a\rightarrow F_{2}(a)$ and because $F_{2}(\gamma)=\phi_{b}\circ\gamma\circ\phi_{a}^{-1}$ ? How will that work?

Comment: The only thing i  have is that $F_{1}F_{2}(f):a\rightarrow d$ for  $f:a\rightarrow d$ in $K_{1}$

Comment: Well, you don't need $F_1$, and also, what I used as $F_2$ is the *restriction* of your $F_2$ to $K_1$. Nevertheless, yes, $\varphi_a$ can be seen as the unit. I gave you a mapping $K_1\to K_2$. Check that it is indeed a functor and find its inverse (in terms of the invertible object mapping $F_2$ and $\varphi_a$'s).